# search results by distinct field - cloudsearch / solr / lucene

Tags: solr, lucene, amazon-cloudsearch

This is on Amazon Cloudsearch, but it probably holds true for any generic Lucene/Solr installation.

I am indexing a bunch of articles and comments on those articles to be searched.  When I search for "Trump sucks", I want the ability to get back a list of comments that match, **or** a list of articles which have comments that match.

I know I can index them in 2 separate domains, but I wonder if there is an easier way to do a "distinct" on a field... in other words...

I have a list of indexed documents for each comment which also contains the article_id as a field .. so:

> id=1 {'article_id':10}
>
> id=2 {'article_id':10}

right now if both of these comments match, I will get back 2 results.  (and yes I can do a distinct on the client side, but it would mess up paging and such).   I want to be able to just get back `[10]`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do distinct in CloudSearch so you will need to come up with another solution.

The best I can offer is to concatenate all comments into a single text field on article records and add a type field to differentiate comments and articles (if you don't already have one). You can then query on type=Article while searching over the concatenated comments and article body and will only ever receive one result per article.

Even with thousands of comments concatenated to a single field on each article I am sure CloudSearch will perform well (maybe even better than with tens of thousands of extra records to concider) however your update process to concatenate all the comments might get heavy. If you do get thousands of comments than adding a flag tracking if it has been concatenated so you don't have to re-build them every time will be helpful.